# Many-to-one association where the association ID (rather than values) is changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a `User` model which `belongs_to :location` (ie. each user can have exactly one location, but a location can be shared by multiple users). The `users` table has a `location_id` column to track this.

If a user wants to change their location, though, I believe that the default behaviour with a Rails association is to change the actual association; in this case, however, I want the existing association (ie. the existing `Location` record) to remain the same, and a new one to be created.

For example, let's say we have users Alice, Bob, Charley and Dave, all of whom have `location_id == 1`, which corresponds to location 123 Sesame St. Then when Dave changes his location to 124 Sesame St., `Location` 1 should not be affected or changed in any way, and `Location` 2 should be created with the new information, and Dave's user record updated to reflect that `location_id` is now 2 instead of 1.

I want to make the changes at the model level (presumably the `User` model), so that if any Location information is changed (`User` also `accepts_nested_attributes_for :location`), the `Location` association is properly updated without overwriting the existing information.

Is there a way to do this, built into Rails or a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` creates a few helper methods for handling nested forms. In your case, you'll want to override setter. This should get you started.

```
class User

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location

  def location_attributes= attrs
    new_location   = Location.where(attrs).first
    new_location ||= Location.create attrs

    self.location = new_location
  end

end
```

And the something like this in your form

```
= f.fields_for :location do |lf|
  .field
    = lf.label      :address
    = lf.text_field :address
  .field
    = lf.label      :city
    = lf.text_field :city
```

Some notes:

- If your user does not have a location at all, the fields for the location won't show. Add a call to `@user.build_location` either in your form or controller.
- You'll probably want to improve the find/create logic, this is a pretty contrived example

If your location model is a single field, you can simplify the whole thing by using a virtual attribute

```
class User
  def location_address= address
    new_location = Location.find_or_create_by_address(address)
    self.location = new_location
  end

  def location_address
    location.address
  end
end
```

In this case, you only need a text field in your form

```
= f.text_field :location_address
```

Comment: `Location` is not just one field (it's got country, state, city, address, etc.), but this is an interesting insight - I wasn't aware of the `location_attributes=` method. I was thinking I'd have to somehow change the record (maybe using `find_or_create_by(...)`, for example) in something like a `before_save`, but this is probably a better idea!

Comment: The only problem I can forsee is what if user.location.attribute is accessed/changed directly? Is there any way to protect it?